# how to select random rows from a table in sql of different categories given as input

Tags: mysql

ex:subject type means g.k,english,maths etc... like that.
my question is for preparing questionpapers by randomly selecting the questions of different questions

Can you please guide regarding this query....?

Comment: It's very unclear to me. Can't you just retrieve all questions and perform randomization on that?

Comment: What is your db schema?

Comment: It means that we will have a table which contains questions of all categories(eng,maths,science,social ...etc).we need to select questions from that table randomly ,which we will give input to that like , the result should contain questions that, from maths-3,science-6,g.k-5

Comment: This is a very poorly articulated question. Reading through the comments, I think what you're trying to ask is "How can I randomly select x number of questions from each category?"

Comment: Search up one of the million greatest-n-per-group questions here on SO and combine it with ORDER BY RAND();

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the best solution but should work: use a `SELECT` Query selecting the top 10 or 20 rows from a query ordered by `RAND`

eg:

> SELECT * FROM questions_table WHERE subject='maths' ORDER BY RAND()
>   LIMIT 0, 10

Comment: some what better,but not only maths it should contain all the subjects in where condition

Comment: if you want it selected from ALL subjects, just remove the where clause, SELECT * FROM questions_table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0, 10

Comment: if you want multiple subjects but not all of them, extend the where clause SELECT * FROM questions_table WHERE subject='maths' OR subject='physics' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0, 10

Comment: but the result may not contain all the subjects

Comment: sir other than that no other option?

Answer (score 1):

```
$sub1=$_POST['sub1'];
$no1=$_POST['no1'];

$sub2=$_POST['sub2'];
$no2=$_POST['no2'];
```

(assuming you are getting these values from a form)

```
mysql_query=('SELECT question FROM question_bank WHERE subject="'.$subj1.'" ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT $no1;

UNION

SELECT question FROM question_bank WHERE subject="'.$subj2.'" ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT $no2;')
```

.... so on... for all the subjects

Comment: thank you sir.another question after selecting 50 questions using above query ,we need to divide 50 questions into 5 sets means that each set must contain 10 ques(assume)

Answer (score 0):

If you want questions from all subjects you can use :

```
SELECT question FROM question_bank ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 50;
```

here 50 is the maximum number of rows in the table upto which you want to search and select the questions.

Now, If you want a subject-wise selection, you can use

```
SELECT question FROM question_bank WHERE subject='GK' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 50;
```

Comment: I think the first query in my answer should help, unless you need a fixed number of questions from each subject.

Comment: yes,we will give fixed no. of questions for each subject

Comment: I think you will need the help of a programming language for this.

Comment: can you help me with the code sir?